# Is it possible to store quartz cronjob config in database (mongoDB)?

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

So I managed to use the quartz scheduler in my JSF web application. Right now the expressions for the triggers are in a quartz_data.xml file like:

```
<schedule>
      <job>
        <name>myCronjob</name>
        <job-class>ch.scheduler.myCronjob</job-class>
    </job>
    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>myCronjob</name>
            <job-name>myCronjob</job-name>
            <cron-expression>0 0/30 * * * ? *</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
    ...
</schedule>
```

Is there a way to store these expressions in a mongoDB.

Comment: any luck with mongodb jobstore?

Answer (score 0):

I am using quartz 1.8.6, so I just review www.quartz-scheduler.org  and get some information for you.

First of all, quartz support jdbc store of course. Quartz offers   JDBC-JobStoreTX to store data in DB. Configuration Reference is [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX.html).

Also, You can download  quartz 2.2.3 from www.quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/ . After you untar the quartz-2.2.3-distribution.tar.gz, you can see the “examples/example13/instance2.properties”. There are some configuration in it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using mongoDB and in the reference it says: JDBCJobStore is used to store scheduling information (job, triggers and calendars) within a relational database.